# How to prevent pytest from adding the LogCaptureHandler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

When a test method (test_*) runs, pytest automatically adds LogCaptureHandler handler to the root logger (http://doc.pytest.org/en/4.2.0/_modules/_pytest/logging.html).

My application has custom logging and log handlers. The root logger always has a stream handler. So I want to prevent pytest from adding the LogCaptureHandler.

What is the purpose of the LogCaptureHandler and is there a way to prevent pytest from adding it?

Comment: Are you looking for `pytest --show-capture=no` or `pytest -s` ? (see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html and https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html)

Comment: It looks like the [`LoggingPlugin._runtest_for_main`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/fcd3fad03da1ca6ebf9cb7d7aa6c7a86cb5a609e/src/_pytest/logging.py#L628) is where `LogCaptureHandler` gets brought in

Comment: Do you know what exactly is the purpose of the LogCaptureHandler? For example - the execution and test running status shown on the output window is from the LogCaptureHandler?

Comment: It's used to capture log records in test and for pretty-printing live logs. You can disable the plugin by running `pytest -p no:logging`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most refined of solutions. Written it as I've needed to test the way a python json logger handles logging an error when an exception occurs inside the logging code `logger.info("something like %d", None)`

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def _without_pytest_log_capture_handler():
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    log_capture_handler = None
    for handler in root_logger.handlers:
        if "LogCaptureHandler" in f"{type(handler)}":
            log_capture_handler = handler
            break
    root_logger.removeHandler(log_capture_handler)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        root_logger.addHandler(log_capture_handler)
```

Usage example:

```py
async def test_json_log_error_handler(aiohttp_client, capsys):

    with _without_pytest_log_capture_handler():
        async def log_handler(_):
            logger = logging.getLogger("some_logger")
            logger.info("something like %d", None)  # pylint: disable=logging-format-interpolation
            return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

        async with _aiohttp_app(aiohttp_client, capsys, "/log", log_handler) as client:
            response = await client.get("/log")
            assert response.status == 200

        out = capsys.readouterr()
        logs = list(map(json.loads, out.err.strip().split("\n")))
        assert len(logs) == 2
        test_log = [x for x in logs if x["logger_name"] == "some_logger"][0]

        assert "--- Logging error ---\nMessage: 'something like %d'\nArguments: (None,)\n" in test_log["msg"]
```